# Declaring a variable causing a syntax error

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make something in pygame to try and learn it and it's trying to yell at me for declaring a variable, whats happening?

the program:

```
#libs
import pygame
import random
import os

#code
def dostuff():
    win.set_caption(random.randint((0,999999))

#init
i = True
win = pygame.display
screen = win.set_mode((1000,500))
while run:
    dostuff()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            i = False
```

and on run it returns this:

```
  File "filename here", line 11
    i = True
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

whats happening?

Comment: Check parenthesis in the statement above. `win.set_caption(random.randint((0,999999))`

Comment: Honestly the new PEG parser is going to be worth it just to make these error messages more useful...

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing parenthesis for set_caption()